# how to design this below UI interface in codename1

Tags: user-interface, codenameone

[/home/benjaminz/Pictures/Screenshot from 2020-02-15 10-01-31.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1JxZ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a really trivial UI.

It can be implemented in multiple ways. E.g. the top line can be tabs with tabs on TOP mode. This will implicitly swap all the lower content for you.

You can place the tabs in the center, add four tabs and the content for each one. In that case you will need a new banner for each page (indicating the sale). Below that you just have a scrollable grid layout that's trivial.

Alternatively the top can be a row of buttons either with grid layout or BoxLayout.X_AXIS.

The page in that case would be a box layout on the Y axis.

The present is a `FloatingActionButton` style component.

The content would be a grid either way.

Each element would be a lead component. With a parent container in a layered layout containing two children One is a border layout containing the image layout in the center and a box y in the south containing both labels. The second one is a top/right aligned flow layout with the discount label.

Comment: If it;s a grid layout then something like `myContainer.add(GridLayout.encloseIn(3, btn1, btn2, btn3);`. If it's a Box layout X then: `myContainer.add(BoxLayout.encloseX(btn1, btn2, btn3);`